# When (if) data dependent AI can think in all ways better than humans, will humans depend on esp or premonition to maintain survival value?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, extinction

I'm working on some big questions to rule a small world. If all intelligence, organic and inorganic sources historical data to think, it seems only foretelling, forecasting, esp, premonition type thinking would remain in the organic domain and potentially give humans a hall pass with AI, as long as we show the results. I'm writing a short story about this, and mainly wondering if this is truly the only other type of thinking AI wouldn't be able to replicate.

Comment: esp = "extrasensory perception"?

Comment: Isn't that rather dependant on how you design your AI in your world? What do you want it to be able to do and not do? At present your question is "author's choice" - i.e. story-based. Please edit to tell us your goals.

Comment: Isn't AI already rather adapt at predictions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So you want to tell a story of race superiority?  Be cautious.

Comment: @JonSG nope. Except possibly predictions along the lines of "_we'll get much more investment if we mention AI and ML in the pitch deck_", perhaps.

Comment: Anyway, with regards to the question: ESP and premonition is magic. As the author, you get to decide how magic works, and whether AI can do magic too. If it _isn't_ magic, then it can be replicated artificially. If it _is_ magic and AI can do it too, then mecha-gandalf will be better at it than his meatbag counterpart in fairly short order.

Comment: Potential AI's cultural contributions are really underestimated ! Enjoy https://www.google.com/doodles/celebrating-johann-sebastian-bach doodle a few notes and click "Harmonize" see what happens hehe

Comment: @Goodies yeah, what gets marketed as "AI" really isn't. Presumably the OP's setting has created actual AGI, though, not just a [big ol' heap of linear algebra](https://xkcd.com/1838/) and an awful lot of human-generated training data.

Comment: @StarfishPrime the AGI can generalize input and actually aquire knowledge from different fields. The opener's AI must do that, so I agree it would be AGI. The Bach doodle does not need that, it learned only one thing, *classic* music theory and harmonics choices. It was done using tensorflow neural nets. This topic made me google it back, the info is on the author's blog https://magenta.tensorflow.org/coconet

Comment: .. and of course we do *not* agree about the Bach Doodle ;) I think it is brilliant, despite the NN technology allowing for simple linear algebra to evaluate things.

Answer (score 2):

There are fatal assumptions about both AI and human brains in this question.

Evolution cannot produce traits that are non physical in nature, as evolution is the change in a population’s genetic traits over time through natural selection. There’s no way that protein folding can violate the laws of physics and give humans telepathy. You could simply write that humans magically develop or are taught ESP and that would be perfectly consistent, but it is strange to say humans could evolve something non physical.

Secondly, machines do not think. Computers lack intentionality and are merely addition machines that are following preset rule sets made by human beings. A computer doesn’t understand anything at all. “Machine Learning” is merely complex statistics.

Comment: Non-biological machines arguably do not think right now, but there's no good reason to think that they *can't* with more technological development  in figuring out cognitive algorithms.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley Cognitive algorithms are merely math. No math ever thought and it never will no matter how complex.

Comment: @NixonCranium If no silicon-based processor can think, then can a carbon-based one? What's the difference between a processing engine made of meat synapses and one made of semiconductors?

Comment: @NixonCranium Quantum chemistry is just math, too. So I guess no organic brain has ever thought or ever will, either. We must just all be philosophical zombies who are only *pretending* to think!

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley This is why physicalist explanations for the mind are false

Comment: @NixonCranium Even if you assert that minds are non-physical, you still have provided no argument that minds can't be hosted by artificial hardware. Just figure out what creates the connection between a non-physical mind and a physical brain, and duplicate it.

Comment: @NixonCranium So you're making the assumption that machines can't be intelligent, and then somehow taking that unsupported assumption as proof that human intelligence isn't physical? That doesn't make sense. Really, we can't say machines can't be intelligent because we simply don't know what intelligence really IS.

Answer (score 1):

If there's some innate magical property to a human soul that a computer can't reproduce, the computer can simply abduct humans and do inhuman experiments with breeding and cybernetics to enhance this esp.

They could also do things like network thousands of human brains together to do greater esp or premonitions deeds, with any unnecessary bodies or brain parts cut away and discarded to add to the feedstock for the next generation of psychic slaves.